# How to add month to entered datetime value?

Tags: jquery

I have one textbox in which i am getting one datetime value for example '7/27/2015 12:00:00 AM', and I have one dropdown list control with the list of Monthly,Quarterly,HalfYearly,Yearly. So how to add only months on that date by changing the dropdown periods?

I tried like below but getting extra months and year not changing if month get above 12.

```
var d = new Date($("#<%=txtActDate.ClientID%>").val());
            var curr_date = d.getDate();                            
            if (packPeriod == 'Monthly') {

                 var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
            var dates = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year;
              alert(dates );
            }
            else if (packPeriod == 'Quarterly') {
              var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 3;
            var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
            var dates = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year;
                alert(dates );
            }
            else if (packPeriod == 'HalfYearly') {
               var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 6;
            var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
            var dates = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year;
                alert(dates );
            }
            else if (packPeriod == 'Yearly') {
              var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 12;
            var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
            var dates = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year;
                alert(dates );
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible problem here is the date format. If you add the attribute type="datetime" to the input element a working code is contained in the following snippet.

For possible date formats you may take a look to [MDN Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Another possible error is the way used to add months: use setMonth.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#periodSelect').on('change', function(e) {
    var d = new Date($("#txtActDate").val());
    var periodSelect = this.value;
    var dates = null;

    switch (periodSelect) {
      case 'Monthly':
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
        dates = d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1)+ "/" + d.getFullYear();
        break;
      case 'Quarterly':
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 3);
        dates = d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1)+ "/" + d.getFullYear();
        break;
      case 'HalfYearly':
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 6);
        dates = d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1)+ "/" + d.getFullYear();
        break;
      case 'Yearly':
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 12);
        dates = d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1)+ "/" + d.getFullYear();
        break;
    }
    if (dates != null) {
      alert(dates );
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<form>
    Date: <input id="txtActDate" type="datetime" value="7/27/2015 12:00:00 AM"><br>
    Period: <select id="periodSelect">
            <option value="">Select a period</option>
            <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
            <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
            <option value="HalfYearly">HalfYearly</option>
            <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
        </select>
</form>
```